# Windows Media Player 11 + 12, with Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am running Ubuntu 15.04. Recently I bought GTA5, and want to play it. I got the .exe and tried to install it using PlayOnLinux but it said I needed the Windows Media Pack.

The answer I received said to change my Wine Config to Windows Vista+, Then I could install WMP (Windows Media Player) 11 + 12, which is what I'd need. The only problem is, wine, even after changing the config to Windows 8, cannot find WMP 11 or 12, only 10. 10 Not being good enough, I've hit a dead end. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install WMP11, you'll need 'cabextract' and the [WMP11 installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/windows-media-player-details.aspx). Also make sure your wine version is set to XP.

`sudo apt-get install cabextract`

1. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   cabextract "/location/to/WMP11/installer.exe" -d $HOME/WMP11
   ```

   (Obviously, you'll have to write the real path/location to WMP11 file)
2. Change to the new created dir:

   ```
   cd $HOME/WMP11
   ```
3. Install WMP11 codecs:

   ```
   wine wmfdist11
   ```

   (You'll have to press Ctrl+C (on terminal) after it finishes installing)

   ```
   wine wmp11
   ```

   (Also press Ctrl+C after it finishes)
4. Set Wine version to 2003 and run WMP11

   It will pass the genuine check but it will crash. You'll have to kill the process (open the 'System Monitor' and kill setup_wm.exe)
5. Run WMP11 again and click continue.

   Now WMP11 starts, although you can barely see it. To fix it click on 'File', press right and select 'Mask Mode'.

There you go. WMP11 is installed and running.

reference [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1093254)

But according to Wine HQ windows media player is rated as [garbage](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=131)

For further reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5296/how-to-install-windows-media-player-11-on-wine)

Comment: what do you mean by apps->Wine->APPS->WMP11?

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but you should be able to install those through winetricks

I can never keep track of exactly which windows components are most common, so I've bookmarked this page.  [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

Comment: Like I've said, using winetricks, It cannot find 11, only 9 + 10

Comment: You should set the Wine Configuration to WindowsXP and manually download Windows Media Player 11 from the MS website. You can then use Playonlinux to install Windows Media Player 11 first and then Install the Game you want. Just keep the Prefix at Windows XP and not change to Windows 7 or 8... See what results get and let me know. I have been maintaining a couple of games on Wine HQ for a while now and I think this way you can .
Here is the link to download WMP.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/windows-media-player-details.aspx

Comment: I tried this solution after posting and I could not get Windows Media Player 11 working...

Windows Media Player 11 is available for  Download free of charge, However the first thing it will want to do is to Validate you Windows License, If it can't do that it will not install. So Technically you can download Windows Media player 11 from MS site but you can't install it under wine no matter what you do ...

Comment: if you set wine prefix Version to anything higher than Windows XP, the Windows Media Player 11 installation fails with different error, which tells me that it is kind of trying to update the existing install of the Prefix and can't find any updates.. Anyhow, I don't think you can get windows media player 11 under wine!.. Let me know if this helps...